# Create custom wpf textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, textbox

I have a textbox displaying a date and time from a DateTime object like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyDate,StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}"/>
```

How can I create a custom textbox, call it DateTextBox, that displays the date already formatted, like this:

```
<DateTextBoxText="{Binding MyDate}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, please seriously consider using a better design, such as utilizing DateTimePicker,

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker

Writing your own TextBox is error prone and inconvenient for your users.

[image]